# Running specified lines of a SAS program

Tags: sas

Assume I have this program:

```
1 data temp;
2   set _null_;
3 run;
4 
5 %put Hello world;
```

and I want to add two lines to it, one that runs lines 1-3 of the program, and another that runs line 5.

The second example [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214504.htm) suggests that %include may be what I'm looking for, but %include 1-3 and %include 5 do not work. %include [path] 1-3 gets me into an infinite loop, which is undesirable.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: %include generally references an external file. I'm not sure there's a way to do what you're trying to do. Can you explain the use case?

Comment: There is a large chunk of code that I need to re-run several times and was looking for a easier way of running it than highlighting everything (loops do not work in this scenario). I can imagine this having other uses as well, but that was my intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: this only works for lines that have previously been submitted.

You need SPOOL option.  I used RESETLINE statement to reset the line number useful when using SAS/EG. I would like to know how you intend to use it.

```
options spool=1;
resetline;
data temp;
   set _null_;
   run;

%put Hello world;

%include 1-3 / source2;
%include 5 / source2;
```

[image]

Comment: resetline statement - nice!

Comment: Ah okay, so maybe this is only a SAS EG capability. Any idea if something can be worked out for base SAS?

Comment: @superfluous It is base SAS running in batch.  EG is just a submitter.  The reason I mentioned EG is because it submits lines of code which is why I did the resetline.

Answer (score 0):

Macros, perhaps?

```
%macro one(datasetname= );
data &datasetname;
set _null_;
run;
%mend one;

%macro two(textstring= ); 
%put &textstring;
%mend two;

%one(datasetname= temp1);
%two(textstring= Hello world);

%one(datasetname= temp2);
%two(textstring= Hello new world);
```

You could feed macro variables into the process from a dataset rather than multiple macro calls. See the examples starting on p 11 here:
[First & Ronk, SGI 130-30, SAS® Macro Variables and Simple Macro Programs](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/130-30.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

A single extra return could screw up your line references...If you need to add a header, or a new line of code somewhere or something are you willing to go back and fix all your line number references?

I recommend using the `macro` or `%include` options.

```
%macro repeat_code();
     ***sas code goes here;

%mend;

%repeat_code
```

For the `%include` you can create the lines inside a new file and then reference them in your code with a `%include`.

Depending on what those lines are actually doing, you may have other options. For example if it's a lookup or re-coding a variable I would use a format instead.